# why am I getting permission denial error?

Tags: permission-denied

/Users/ashkannan/.zprofile:12: permission denied: /Users/ashkannan/Radex/bin

I keep getting the above error when ever I launch my terminal. How do I fix this?

I am pretty new to python and have not been trying too many things to fix it.

Comment: The message suggests that the problem lies at line 12 of your .zprofile. Please edit your question and provide the content so we can examine what may be happenig.

Comment: the terminal launches with this error message. I deleted the Radex folder from the computer, now its saying the file is not found. But, Why in the first place is my terminal trying to launch radex. It never did that before.

Comment: There is no point in just deleting a file and hoping the problem will go away. You need to find out what causes the problem. So please provide the information I asked for in my previos comment.